# use try-with-resources to close a Closeable

Tags: java, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I have a `Map<Key, Closeable>` and if a key is removed from the map I want to close the `Closeable`. Normally I have something like:

```
Closeable c = map.remove(key);
c.close();
```

My Eclipse warns me "Resource 'c' should be managed by try-with-resource", so is it better just to write the following?

```
try (Closeable c = map.remove(key)) {}
```

In my special implementation I have a subclass of `Closeable`, where `close()` does not throw an `IOException`, so no exception handling is needed.

Comment: it auto call `c.close()` after `try` block

Comment: It is good to use `try-with-resources` statement, so what is your question?

Comment: Can you give more details about the Closeable objects, why they are put in a map and why they need to be closed when they are removed from that map?

Comment: You could eliminate `c` by writing `map.remove(key).close()`.

Comment: @Jerry06 I know what it does, I just want to know the best practice.
@YuJiaao As matoni stated in his answer "Empty try-with-resource looks weird.", so I asked.
@KevinKrumwiede You are right, but this is not the question.
@WilQu It is used in a ServerSocket process. The map saves the active client connections. On disconnect or timeout they are removed from this map and the listening `Thread` will be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of try-with-resources is that:

- The opening of the `Closeable` resource is done in the `try` statement
- The use of the resource is inside the `try` statement's block
- `close()` is called for you automatically.

So your suggested code:

```
try(Closeable c = map.remove(key)) {}
```

... doesn't satisfy the point of try-with-resource, since you're not using the resource inside the block. Presumably your `Closeable` is already open before this statement.

I'm guessing that you have some code whereby a bunch of resources are opened, work is done, then they are all closed by working through the map.

This is OK, and sometimes unavoidable. But it's cleaner, where possible, to have `open()` and `close()` in the same method, with the `close()` in a `finally` block, so that you can see at a glance that every `open()` has a corresponding `close()` and you can be sure that the `close()` is always called.

```
MyCloseable c = MyCloseable.open(...);
try{
       // do stuff with c;
} finally {
     try {
         c.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // ...
     }
}
```

Once you've achieved that, try-with-resources just makes things neater:

```
try(MyCloseable c = MyCloseable.open(...)) {
    // do stuff with c;
}
```

If your requirements mean you can't get open and close into the same methods, then just stick with an explicit `close()` and ignore the warning.

Comment: Theoretical the resources can be open forever since it is a Client-Server communication and the client can be logged in forever if there is no timeout.

Answer (score 3):

I would just ignore this warning, If you are managing close operation on your own, then just call `close()`. Empty try-with-resource looks weird.

Consider to extend Map so close operation will be performed automatically on remove:

```
public class CloseableMap<K,V extends Closeable> extends HashMap<K,V> {

    @Override
    public R remove(K key) {
        V resource = super.remove(key);
        if (resource != null) {
            resource.close();
        }
        return resource;
    }
}
```